# c# 4.0 - best way to refactor a block of "If (something is Type) {}" statements?

Tags: types, c#-4.0, refactoring

I've got some code that looks like this,

```
public void ResetControls(Control controlOnPage)
{
    if (controlOnPage is TextBox)
    {
        ResetTextBoxControl(controlOnPage);
    }

    if (controlOnPage is MediaPicker)
    {
        ((MediaPicker)controlOnPage).Media = null;
    }

    if (controlOnPage is RelatedContentPicker)
    {
        ((RelatedContentPicker)controlOnPage).RelatedContentCollection = null;
    }
    ...
    ...

    foreach (Control child in controlOnPage.Controls)
    {
        ResetControls(child);
    }
}
```

The idea behind it is that I can pass a page to the method and it'll recursively reset all the controls on it to their default states - in the case of MediaPicker and RelatedContentPicker, these are user controls that I've created.

FXCop warns me "Do Not Cast Unnecessarily" for this code - but I'm unsure how to rewrite it to make it better.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that FXCop doesn't like the code, because a nice object-oriented solution would be to add virtual method `ResetControl` to the `Control` class (which you, of course, cannot do).

If you wanted a clear object-oriented solution, you could create an interface `IResetableControl` and create a derived class for each of the control that would implement the interface.

If you just want to make the existing code syntactically nicer, you can use the following helper method:

```
public void IfCast<T>(object obj, Action<T> f) {
  if (obj is T) f((T)obj);
}
```

Then you could just write:

```
IfCast(controlOnPage, (TextBox t) =>
    ResetTextBoxControl(t));

IfCast(controlOnPage, (MediaPicker mp) => {
    mp.Media = null; });
```

This has exactly the same semantics as your original code, but it is a bit nicer (and I think that FxCop will accept it). Note that the generic type parameter is infered from the type specified in the lambda expression e.g. `(TextBox t)`. This also removes the need to do additional casting inside the code that handles the case, because you already get a value of the right type (e.g. `mp`).

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious thing to do is to throw in an `else` in front of the `if`'s:

```
if (controlOnPage is TextBox)
{
    ResetTextBoxControl(controlOnPage);
}

else if (controlOnPage is MediaPicker)
{
    ((MediaPicker)controlOnPage).Media = null;
}

else if (controlOnPage is RelatedContentPicker)
{
    ((RelatedContentPicker)controlOnPage).RelatedContentCollection = null;
}
```

There is no need to try to cast to `MediaPicker` or `RelatedContentPicker` if the control is a `TextBox`. I'd also order them so that more common cases comes before less common cases.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the duplicated cast, you could transform this:

```
if (controlOnPage is MediaPicker)
{
    ((MediaPicker)controlOnPage).Media = null;
}
```

to be:

```
MediaPicker mediaPickerControl = controlOnPage as MediaPicker;
if (mediaPickerControl != null)
{
    mediaPickerControl.Media = null;
}
```

Repeat for your other casts.

You could also combine this with some nested cases so that you don't have to try to do the cast if you know it was already something else, such as a Textbox

Comment: This destroys the (imho) readable chain of "if control is SomeType" statements and hides the question about the type in the cast before the `if`. I wouldn't say this is an improvement.

Comment: @Johannes it does get rid of the duplicated cast though.

Comment: But sacrificing readability for (dubious) performance improvements isn't always the right thing. I'd say that can be eliminated by the compiler as well.

Comment: @Johannes: I don't think this is eliminated by the compiler, but I agree that writing it as you have is much clearer to the reader. It will be very very slightly slower than Rowland's code, but it's likely that this doesn't matter. However, Rowland's answer will also get rid of the FXCop error, as with this you're casting once instead of twice.

Comment: @Johannes The fxCop warning is telling you that it **hasn't** been eliminated by the compiler. As I mention in my post, there's always the possibility of chaining these in some conditional logic. Of course, readability is subjective, too...